# IT Hit Ajax Library - MODApplet.class Not Found

Tags: webdav, ithit-ajax-file-browser

When I try to open .txt, .pdf or .odt by calling:

```
'ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.EditDocument(sDocumentUrl, javaApletFilePath)`
```

I noticed with Fiddler a GET request on /MODApplet.class with a 404 Not Found response.
Is it normal ?

**Additional information:**

I first tested the library on a simple configuration and everything worked fine so I didn't use Fiddler to look at requests and responses.

Since I have changed the configuration I have problems when editing .odt, .pdf and .doc but I can't figure out where it comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the request to /MODApplet.class and 404 Not Found response is normal. This is done for maximum web browser compatibility as far as I remember. But make sure the request to ITHitMountOpenDocument.jar is fulfilled.

As soon as you mention reconfiguration you may need to cleanup Java cache on a client computer, pleas see the screenshot:

[image]

If you changed the authentication schema you may need to clean the cached credentials, please see "Credentials and Authentication Schema Caching" [here](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/windows/miniredirector).

- **Regarding .odt files**: LibreOffice and OpenOffice does not provide any
  web browser add-ins or protocol extensions to open documents without Java applet. However LibreOffice/OpenOffice documents can be opened via Java applet directly from server with no problem.
- **Regarding .pdf documents**: Hypothetically Adobe Acrobat provides web browser add-ins to open documents directly from server. From our experience it never worked properly, you always get an error. Again Java applet should be ok with it.
- **Regarding .doc documents**: There should be no problems opening .doc files both via web browser add-ins/protocol extensions and Java applet. Please also take a look at [this article](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/ms_office_read_only).

Comment: I have cleared both Java cache and cached credentials but no improvements.
When you say that it can be opened via Java applet, by calling EditDocument, Java applet is used when there is no MS Office installed or when it's not a Microsoft Office document, isn't it ?
I email you the Fiddler log